# Prometheus is throwing "bad response status 401 Unauthorized" - Even afer specificying right configs "basic_auth_users"

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I've configured user & prod ("basic_auth_users") and passed those parameters as mentioned in the doc:
--web.config.file

Able to access Prometheus UI and Alert Manager UI independently(with provided credentials) but I'm seeing the following error in Prometheus logs and alerts aren't going out due to this.

```
level=error ts=2021-08-16T07:00:53.337Z caller=notifier.go:527 component=notifier alertmanager=http://pronode1:9093/api/v1/alerts count=1 msg="Error sending alert" err="bad response status 401 Unauthorized"
```

Ideally  `alertmanager=http://pronode1:9093/api/v1/alerts`  requires user and password to be able to get results but then why is it not picking up from the `--web.config.file`file i provided.

```
# Alertmanager configuration
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      - pronode1:9093
```

Am I missing any other configuration?

Please help me.

Version used:

```
 Prometheus: prometheus-2.25.2.linux-amd64 
 AlertManager: alertmanager-0.22.2.linux-amd64
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you expecting Prometheus to pick up the username and password to use for the request it makes to Alertmanager from the `web.config.file`? I don't think that's a feature: that configuration is used when acting as a HTTP *server*, not when acting as a HTTP *client*. How would it even know which user name to pick?

(Not to mention that passwords in the `web.config.file` are hashed, so it's not even in theory possible to use them for making a request.)

The [<alertmanager_config>](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/configuration/configuration/#alertmanager_config) section has a `basic_auth` block you can use to configure a username and password for the outgoing request. It would look something like:

```
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
  - static_configs:
    - targets:
      - pronode1:9093
    basic_auth:
      username: foo
      password: bar
```

(Or with `password_file` instead of `password` if you don't want it in the same configuration file.)