# Monitoring JWT secured APIs using Prometheus

Tags: jwt, prometheus

I have been using Prometheus and exporter for monitoring purpose. I am stuck on one point to monitor status code and response time of API which required JWT authentication. Is there any way to monitor APIs which required JWT authentication?

I am expecting to get proper status code of API like 200 or 500 and not 401(unauthorised) or 404 (not found).

Comment: What is your exact problem? Blackbox exporter exposes `probe_http_status_code` where you'll get you 401. Or is that not what you want?

Comment: please check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68800103/prometheus-is-throwing-bad-response-status-401-unauthorized-even-afer-specif